# ctype_alpha but allow spaces(php)

Tags: php

I was wondering if one can allow spaces in a textfield when checking it with ctype_alpha. Since ctype_alpha only allows alphabetical letters, I don't know how to let the user enter space in the field. I did try using ctype_space but that didn't work. I simply want the user to be able to type only alphabets and they have a choice to include spaces if they "wish." I hope I will not have to use regexp.

```
elseif (!ctype_alpha($fname))
{
    echo "Your name may only contain alphabetical letters";   
}
```

Answer (score 32):

this is what I would do

```
if (!ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $fname)))
```

this allows for spaces only, but if you want to allow more than just spaces, like punctuation or what not, [read up on str_replace][1], it allows for arrays

```
str_replace(array(' ', "'", '-'), '', $fname)
```

I'm suggesting this because First Name may have apostrophe and last name may also have dashes
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it worked, and ofcourse also thanks for the link!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you Raj. If this satisfies your requirements and you are not looking for other suggestions, I would kindly appreciate if you mark the answer as accepted :)
Cheers

Comment: + 1 Creative solution allows other chars to fly under the radar. I was thinking about using this function but need to also include "-" and "_", thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that also by simply removing space before you do ctype_alpha.

```
$fname=str_replace(" ", "", $fname);

if(!ctype_alpha($fname)){
  echo "Your name may only contain alphabetical letters";
}
```

Comment: Validating a string which consists of spaces only results in a false this way while it should result in a true. This because ctype_alpha returns false (php > v5.1) on an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the spaces is the way to go, but remember ctype_alpha results in a false on an empty string these days!
Below the method I use...

```
function validateAlpha($valueToValidate, $spaceAllowed = false) {
    if ($spaceAllowed) {
        $valueToValidate = str_replace(' ', '', $valueToValidate);
    }
    if (strlen($valueToValidate) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return ctype_alpha($valueToValidate);
}
```