# AJAX search doesn't work with spaces

Tags: php, database

I have problem when user types with spaces into live Ajax search it doesn't show any results. When user types only half of word without spaces it works fine. I think its something with Ajax, but can't find any solution here.. Maybe you can suggest something.. Thanks.

Ajax:

```
function ajaxFunction(str)
        {
            var httpxml;
            try
            {
                // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
                httpxml = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                // Internet Explorer
                try
                {
                    httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e)
                    {
                        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            function stateChanged()
            {
                if (httpxml.readyState == 4)
                {
                    document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML = httpxml.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("msg").style.display = 'none';

                }
            }
            var url = "search-ajax.php";
            url = url + "?txt=" + str;
            url = url + "&sid=" + Math.random();
            httpxml.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
            httpxml.open("GET", url, true);
            httpxml.send(null);
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Please Wait ...";
            document.getElementById("msg").style.display = 'inline';

        }
```

search-ajax.php:

```
    error_reporting(0);

require "search_con.php";


$in = $_GET['txt'];
if (!ctype_alnum($in)) {
    echo "";
    exit;
}
$msg = "";
$msg = "<div id=results style=position:absolute;z-index: 10;right:0px;background-color:#302b2b;>";
if (strlen($in) > 0 and strlen($in) < 20) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%$in%' LIMIT 17";
    foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $nt) {

        $name = $nt['name'];

        $msg .='<div>' . $name . '<div>';
    }
}
$msg .='</div>';
echo $msg;
```

What could it be? Thanks for all your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function ctype_alnum will return false if the text contains a space. So maybe your script stops there ?

```
$in = $_GET['txt'];

//always occurs when a space is in the $in variable.
if (!ctype_alnum($in)) 
{
    echo "";
    exit;
}
```

Make sure you use trim() BEFORE you make that check. That check will also stop any search for a text which as space inside the text like "New year".

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove leading and trailing spaces of `txt` in your PHP script:

```
$in = trim($_GET['txt']);
```

Comment: What exactly do you type in? If you are typing in more than one word you probably have to split the search string and check them separately in your SQL query.

Comment: Im typing for example : "New Year" - search doesn't work, but when I type: "New" - search works perfectly.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936862/ctype-alpha-but-allow-spacesphp `ctype_alpha` returns `false` if there are spaces in your string. Do you really need this check by using `ctype_alpha`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I realised that I don't need this block of code.

```
if (!ctype_alnum($in)) {
echo "";
exit;
```

}

Comment: Great! But you should also use `$in = trim($_GET['txt']);` so that searching for "New York  " will also work ;-)